# Multi Level / Hierarchical Time Series Models in Python

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistical-significance, python

I have data with different leaders and their performance score over a period of time. I need to analyse this time series data where data for each leader should be considered different time series data. I tried Autoregression model but as per my research it doesn't have functionality to perform multi level analysis like in LMER. Is there any way I can do the multilevel analysis on the time series data?

Comment: Is your aim to analyse the time series separately or jointly?

Comment: @utobi separately but simultaneously  like we do in the case mentioned in this post https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/mixed_lm_example.html

Comment: (1) what is the aim of your analyses ? (in the linked post the curves are modelled jointly) (2) are the time points regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python support for hierarchical time series is pretty poor. What you want to do is developed very nicely in R [Hierarchical/Grouped time series](https://otexts.com/fpp2/hierarchical.html)

However, there are active/dead developments of the same/similar in python that you can take a look.

1. [pyaf](https://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf) has an implementation of [hierarchical time series](https://github.com/antoinecarme/pyaf/blob/master/docs/PyAF_Hierarchical_FrenchWineExportation.ipynb)
2. [scikit-hts](https://scikit-hts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is the python implementation of Hyndman's work.
3. [Hierarchical forecast](https://github.com/Nixtla/hierarchicalforecast/tree/main/)

Documentation is pretty poor and each of them will have specific bugs around them. Might not be reliable for commercial implementation.